# Error message for table rate is not displaying how to fix in magento 2

Tags: magento2, table-rates

I have created a table rate it works fine, but if we give wrong pin number it does not shows error message instead it shows as "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time". how can i fix it

Comment: can you tell me, which error message you are talking about?

Comment: "display error message" which in under table rate ,i want to display my own error message ,when the customer gives wrong pin code

Comment: Then you wanto to make custom code for that.

Comment: how can i make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from this comes from KO which uses CSV file

You can try to edit the CSV file or rather create your own CSV file in your module like i18n/en_US.csv,

And edit there like

```
"Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time","Your text here"
```

You can also try using inline translation tool that Magento has

```
Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Translate Inline > Enable for Storefront
```

Comment: Thank u so much it works for me

Comment: Glad to help!!!